# here-api, cant get the off-street parking api to work

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest, parking

I registered to here rest api's and I succeeded to get the bearer token.
from some reason, when I try to create http request to "https://parking-v2.cit.cc.api.here.com/parking/facilities.json" with the right parameters and the token, I get the following response: {"error":"Forbidden","error_description":"These credentials do not authorize access"}. When I request some other api's, like the weather: "https://weather.cc.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json", it works fine.
Is it possible that parking api doesn't use the same token or different authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the off-street parking is not part of your plan. Please go to the page https://developer.here.com/help and fill out the information, someone from HERE will reach out to you to grant you access to it.